# Working with WKT data in XML File in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, fme-form, xml, well-known-text

Anyone have experience with importing XML files into SQL server 2008 or 2012 that have a WKT element that includes the geometry for each feature?  I can get this to easily work using FME software but wondering if this can't be done directly using SQL Server.  In FME I used the GeometryReplacer transformer. These XML files have all of the WKT data in a single XML element for each feature.